Geometric intuition for highly non-normal matrix?
From related question

highly non-normal linear system gives slow convergence for linear solvers. Is there geometric intuition why?

Figure in 7.2 of Corless/Fillion book :

Higham suggests using $\tau(A)$ the difference between squared singular value/eigenvalue magnitudes as a measure of non-normality of a matrix $A$:
$$\tau(A)=\sum_i |\sigma_i|^2 - |\lambda_i|^2$$

Is there geometric intuition for what kinds of linear operations make this measure high?

Below is a simple test in $d=2$, combining stretching with a rotation.
$$A(\theta)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 10 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (\theta ) & -\sin (\theta ) \\
 \sin (\theta ) & \cos (\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
It seems like deviation from normality is highest $(\tau=81)$ when strong scaling is combined with a strong rotation $(\theta\approx \pi/2)$. Can this intuition be extended to higher dimensions?


Here's what eigenvalues look like for various values of $\theta$

Notebook
